# storing, updating and deleting data from app.controller angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I am struggling with some Javascript that I am currently working on. So I have a simple web application and the following is the AngularJS stuff:

```
app.filter('startFrom', function () {
    return function (input, start) {
        if (input) {
            start = +start;
            return input.slice(start);
        }
        return [];
    };
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'filterFilter', function ($scope, filterFilter) {
    $scope.items = ["name 1", "name 2", "name 3"
    ];

    $scope.addLink = function () {
        $scope.errortext = "";
        if (!$scope.newItem) {return;}
        if ($scope.items.indexOf($scope.newItem) == -1) {
            $scope.items.push($scope.newItem);
            $scope.errortext = "submitted";
        } else {
            $scope.errortext = " in list";
        }
    };
```

So I have these and I there is html side of it which displays the list of items. Users have options to add and delete these items from items array.
Question. How do I make sure that when user added or deleted items from the array can still see the edited list after reloading the page? Can someone suggest a way of dealing with it? Would it be possible to store in cookies and after each add/delete action update them, if so how?

thanks

UPDATE:
So I changed the script but it still does not seem to be working.

```
var app = angular.module('App', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.filter('startFrom', function () {
    return function (input, start) {
        if (input) {
            start = +start;
            return input.slice(start);
        }
        return [];
    };
});

app.factory('ItemsService', ['$window', function ($window) {
    var storageKey = 'items',
        _sessionStorage = $window.sessionStorage;
    return {
        // Returns stored items array if available or return undefined
        getItems: function () {
            var itemsStr = _sessionStorage.getItem(storageKey);

            if (itemsStr) {
                return angular.fromJson(itemsStr);
            }
        },
        // Adds the given item to the stored array and persists the array to sessionStorage
        putItem: function (item) {
            var itemsStr = _sessionStorage.getItem(storageKey),
                items = [];

            if (itemStr) {
                items = angular.fromJson(itemsStr);
            }

            items.push(item);

            _sessionStorage.setItem(storageKey, angular.toJson(items));
        }
    }
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'filterFilter', 'ItemsService', function ($scope, filterFilter, ItemsService) {
    $scope.items = ItemsService.get($scope.items)

    $scope.addLink = function () {
        $scope.errortext = "";
        if (!$scope.newItem) {
            return;
        }
        if ($scope.items.indexOf($scope.newItem) == -1) {
            $scope.items.push($scope.newItem);
            $scope.errortext = "Submitted";
            $scope.items = ItemsService.put($scope.items)
        } else {
            $scope.errortext = "Link in the list";
        }
    };

    $scope.removeItem = function (item) {
        $scope.items.splice($scope.items.indexOf(item), 1);
        $scope.items = ItemsService.put($scope.items)
        $scope.resetFilters;
    };
}]);
```

**Any help how to fix it and how to make sure that if user does not have any items it will use the default $scope.items = ["name 1", "name 2", "name 3"]; ?**

Comment: There is an Angular services for cookies $cookie.
You can add/edit them at any time.

Comment: More than cookies, it is right to store and retrieve from sessionStorage.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple get/set service that is using `$cookies`. It could be like this :

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('ItemsService', ['$cookies', function($cookies) {
    var cookieName = 'items'
    return {
      get: function(defaults) {
        return $cookies.get(cookieName).split(',') || defaults
      },
      put: function(items) {
        var expireDate = new Date()
        expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate() + 1);
        $cookies.put(cookieName, items.join(','), { expires: expireDate } )
      }
    }
}]);
```

Include `ItemsService` in your controller and in the main function

```
$scope.items = ItemsService.get($scope.items)
```

to get the edited list stored in `$cookies` (if any), and save the list in `addLink()` by

```
ItemsService.put($scope.items)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to extend @davidkonrad's answer here, by making his service to use sessionStorage. Since using sessionStorage is most suited for your usecase.

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('ItemsService', ['$window', function($window) {
     var storageKey = 'items',
        _sessionStorage = $window.sessionStorage;

     return {
        // Returns stored items array if available or return undefined
        getItems: function() {
            var itemsStr = _sessionStorage.getItem(storageKey);

            if(itemsStr) {
                return angular.fromJson(itemsStr);
            }         

            return ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']; // return default value when there is nothing stored in sessionStore                
        },
        // Adds the given item to the stored array and persists the array to sessionStorage
        putItem: function(item) {
            var itemsStr = _sessionStorage.getItem(storageKey),
            items = [];

            if(itemStr) {
                items = angular.fromJson(itemsStr);
            }

            items.push(item);

            _sessionStorage.setItem(storageKey, angular.toJson(items));
        }
     }
}]);
```

Comment: In the case I have a list and user deletes one or more items, is it enough to use -> ItemsService.put($scope.items) ?

Comment: I have updated my original question since I can't figure out the way to solve it. Any help? @MuthukannanKanniappan

Comment: I have updated my answer, so the getItems returns a default array. Also please note the function names in the ItemsService, it is getItems and putItem, I find you have referred it wrongly in your controller.

Comment: I added the edited stuff but when I put the line $scope.items = ItemsService.getItems($scope.items); into my controller everything breaks. Any solution you can think of?

Comment: But with line: $scope.items = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']; controller functions fine? Is the something wrong with the way I am using ItemsService?